# Filter out combinations in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, filter, combinations

Currently I can generate all the combinations from categories alpha, beta, gamma and delta (1 1 1 1, 1 1 1 2 etc.).

Current code:

```
alpha = [1, 2, 3];
beta  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
gamma = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
delta = [1, 2, 3];
[a, b, c, d] = ndgrid (alpha, beta, gamma, delta);
combination = [a(:), b(:), c(:), d(:)];
```

I want to filter out some of those combinations i.e. get rid of any of the combinations where alpha is 1 and gamma is 4 etc.

How would I approach this?

Comment: Could you post your code as text rather than an image? We can't cut and paste from an image to run the code.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

```
c1 = (combination(:,1) ~= 1); %rows where alpha is not 1
c2 = (combination(:,3) ~= 4); %rows where gamma is not 4

desired = combination(c1&c2,:); %output rows where both c1 and c2 are true
```

Comment: also, you don't want to select those rows, you want to get *rid* of them, so you should either reverse your logical array or the logical tests.

Comment: (I took the liberty of correcting it for you, I hope that's ok)

Comment: It wasn't quite clear to me whether they were to be removed, or highlighted. I've heard "filtered out" both ways. Thanks for catching my typo

Answer (score 1):

Ian Riley's answer has provided the correct approach if you want to create a new array from that information. Just adding to his answer that you can also use the same approach to remove the unwanted rows directly, by setting them to empty, i.e.:

```
>> combination(combination(:,1) == 1,:) = [];
>> combination(combination(:,3) == 4,:) = [];
```